# How to get transaction dependency in python?

Tags: python

I'm looking for oss for python transaction dependency(or transaction analysis graph).

example
→

```
{
    "stacktrace" : [
        {
            "method" : "<src-method: < Source, Lcom/ibm/websphere/samples/daytrader/web/TradeAppServlet, doPost(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V >>",
                "file" : "/app/daytrader-ee7-web/src/main/java/com/ibm/websphere/samples/daytrader/web/TradeAppServlet.java",
                "position" : "TradeAppServlet.java [98:8] -> [98:38]"
        }
    ],
    "sql" : "insert into accountprofileejb ( userid, passwd, fullname, address, email, creditcard ) VALUES (  ?  ,  ?  ,  ?  ,  ?  ,  ?  ,  ?  )"
}
```

In the example, this is the result of analyzing a JAVA project using OSS called tackle-diva.
If there is any similar OSS or information in Python, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.